# how do i create and insert a node inside another node

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm trying to insert an xml node with another child xml node in an existing xmldocument in C#.
I've got an XML doc that looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DictionarySerializer>
    <item>
        <key>statusCode</key>
        <value>0</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>statusSeverity</key>
        <value>INFO</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>statusMessage</key>
        <value>Status OK</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>MerchantAccountNumber</key>
        <value>9999999999</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>ReconBatchID</key>
        <value>420150418 1Q02144266965047801046AUTO04</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>PaymentGroupingCode</key>
        <value>3</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>responsePaymentStatus</key>
        <value>Completed</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>TxnAuthorizationTime</key>
        <value>2015-04-18T09:14:41</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>TxnAuthorizationStamp</key>
        <value>1429348481</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>ClientTransID</key>
        <value>aidjl79f</value>
    </item>
</DictionarySerializer>
```

and I need to insert another  node with a  node and  node at the bottom.
I have this so far:

```
  XmlDocument xmlCustomValues = new XmlDocument();
            xmlCustomValues.LoadXml(OldCustomValues);
            XmlNode NodeItem = xmlCustomValues.SelectSingleNode("DictionarySerializer");
            XmlNode NodeNewItem = xmlCustomValues.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "item", null);
    XmlNode NodeNewKey = NodeNewItem.??????
```

but not sure how to create a node under NodeNewItem (there's no "CreateNode" method). Never done this before (obviously) and the syntax does not make sense to me.

---

here's an answer that worked (test code for XML doc above)

```
  string OldCustomValues = this.txtInput.Text;
    XmlDocument xmlCustomValues = new XmlDocument();
    xmlCustomValues.LoadXml(OldCustomValues);
    XmlNode NodeItem = xmlCustomValues.SelectSingleNode("DictionarySerializer");
    XmlNode NodeNewItem = xmlCustomValues.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "item", null);
    NodeItem.AppendChild(NodeNewItem);
    XmlNode NodeNewKey = xmlCustomValues.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "key", null);
    NodeNewKey.InnerText = "MyKey";
    XmlNode NodeNewValue = xmlCustomValues.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "value", null);
    NodeNewValue.InnerText = "MyValue";
    NodeNewItem.AppendChild(NodeNewKey);
    NodeNewItem.AppendChild(NodeNewValue);

    this.txtOutput.Text = xmlCustomValues.OuterXml;
```

Comment: does this work for u?

Comment: Like this?
NodeItem.AppendChild(NodeNewItem);
            XmlNode NodeNewKey = xmlCustomValues.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "key", null);
            NodeNewKey.InnerText = "MyKey";
            XmlNode NodeNewValue = xmlCustomValues.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "value", null);
            NodeNewValue.InnerText = "MyValue";
       NodeNewItem.AppendChild(NodeNewKey);
            NodeNewItem.AppendChild(NodeNewValue);

Comment: sorry, the comments section really needs to be better on StackExchange (no way to format!!!)

Comment: it seams to be good, what r the results?

Comment: I added: this.txtOutput.Text = xmlCustomValues.OuterXml; to convert back to a string (test project).
It worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already created the node, u just need to append the node to the root

```
NodeItem.AppendChild(NodeNewItem);
```